# UnknownHostException after the attempt of reading a XML file

Tags: java, xml, exception, xom

I have to serialise key/values of a map to a XML file, and then deserialise them.

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
// ...
LinkedList<Element> l = new LinkedList<Element>();
Element root = new Element("root");
for (String str : map.keySet()) {
     l.add(new Element(str)); // key
     l.getLast().appendChild(map.get(str).toString()); // value
     root.appendChild(l.getLast());
}
Document d = new Document(root);

BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("data.xml"));
out.write(d.toXML());
out.close();

d = new nu.xom.Builder().build("data.xml"); // !
Elements e = d.getRootElement().getChildElements();
```

But when I try to read the XML file, `UnknownHostException` is thrown on the marked line.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: file
```

The XML file is created succesfully though. The formatted version looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <through>1</through>
    <don>1</don>
    <backed>1</backed>
    <I>2</I>
    <asList>1</asList>
// ....
</root>
```

Could you please explain me what is the problem?

Comment: do you know what `build()` is taking as parameter, if its file name then provide the full path to the file.

Comment: you should follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the doc pointed by @delephin, its better to use `build(File in)` version of `build` method, pass the `File` instance associated with your `data.xml` to your `build()` method, as below

```
 d = new nu.xom.Builder().build(new File("data.xml"));
```

Comment: That is better! :)

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The build method expects an URL: [Builder.build(String)](http://www.xom.nu/apidocs/nu/xom/Builder.html#build(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a proper URL to `build()`, this includes local files.

You can get the URL for a local file using:

```
new File(path).toURI().toURL();
```